# Excel not responding when I try to open VBE

Tags: vba, excel

I need help, Excel is not responding. I have written a lot of code in VBA and right now I can't even open VBE. I can open the workbook okay, but every time I make any change to one of the cells (I have a lot of code that is triggered by the worksheet_change event based on the cell that was changed) it will not respond. I'm 80% sure it is something wrong with my code, but I can't open the VBE to diagnose because that will also cause Excel to not respond, forcing me to close the application.

I have tried opening Excel in user-initiated safe mode, but this doesn't fix anything.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have any add-ins installed?

Comment: @RubberDuck I have MZ-Tools installed. Checking the box for "Disable all  Application Add-ins" didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: Try to open the file on another computer and see if the editor opens. If it does then the problem is on your computer, otherwise is on the file. Let us know if it's on the file or on the computer, and whatever error message you get.

Comment: @stenci I will try that. In the mean time, with the suggestions I have received implemented, when I change the value of a cell now, it gives me "Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error."

If I click on Debug, it will cause Excel to hang and not respond. If I click on End it will return to my spreadsheet.

Comment: Since I have been working on trying to get this open since 10 pm last night, I finally decided to roll back to a previously saved revision I had saved. Thanks for trying to help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Change your *Security Settings* to prevent macro execution.  You can then open file and examine the macros without fear they will execute.

EDIT#1:

[image]

Comment: What _Security_ _Settings_ are you talking about? I have changed the Trust Center: Macro Security settings to "Disable all macros with notification" but that didn't change things.

Comment: @BGeorge  In **Excel Options**  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have performed that change, but am still unable to open the Visual Basic Editor.

Comment: you would have your excel reinstalled faster than all you did here i guess

Answer (score -1):

Close all files and programs.  Then, restore your computer to an earlier time period.  You can find out how to do this in 'Control Panel'.  This will fix it.

Comment: this is not proper answer to this question. How you can restore your computer ?